# Primefaces wizard showing progress

Tags: tabs, wizard, primefaces

I want to use Primefaces to display a wizard pretty much similar to the one shown in the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/wizard.jsf), but with some kind of tabview that displays the progress of the user, thus **combining the wizard with the [tabView](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/tabview.jsf)**.

Because I think this is quite a common requirement I was wondering if anyone tried the same and could give me some **suggestions on how to do it**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout primefaces latest release 2.2 that has a new feature of wizard progress step by step